# Start radare2 with pre-set visual mode configuration

Tags: radare2

This is the way I like to RE with radare visual mode. But I have to configure it everytime I start r2. How can I make it so r2 starts with this visual everytime I enter visual mode?[image: My r2 during RE]

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `~/.radare2rc` to make configs / cmds automatically run everytime radare2 is launched. You'll have to set a flag inside of that so it loads up the visual configuration you have everytime it's ran.

[Example .radare2rc](https://github.com/xn0px90/radare2rc) Here is a fine example I found on GitHub. You use the flag `eco theme_name` to set a default theme on launch.